# Sorting the nodes of a Networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, graph, networkx

I have the following graph to which I delete and add nodes, edges.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=15, seed=1)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
print(pos)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, pos, 'pos')
G.remove_edge(2, 9)
largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
G = G.subgraph(largest_cc).copy()
G.add_node(2, pos=pos[2])
G.add_edge(2, 8)
print(G.edges)
print(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'pos'))
print(G.nodes)
```

The final outputs aren't sorted, the following is the numbering if the nodes (attributes aren't sorted as well)

```
print(G.nodes)
[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2]
```

Expected output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I would like to know how to create a sorted graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By building a subgraph using the nodes in the largest connected component, you're removing that second node:

```
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=10, m=15, seed=1)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, pos, 'pos')

G.remove_edge(2, 9)
largest_cc = max(nx.connected_components(G), key=len)
G.nodes()
# NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

G = G.subgraph(largest_cc).copy()
G.nodes()
# NodeView((0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

Now by adding node `2` again, `G.add_node(2, pos=pos[2])`, this is essentially updating the node data dictionary (the internal data structure in which it is saved), literally with `dict.update`:

```
d = dict(G.nodes(data=True))
d.update({2:{'pos':[0.3, 0.5]}})
print(d)
{0: {'pos': array([ 0.33041585, -0.07185971])},
 1: {'pos': array([-0.19659528,  0.33972794])},
 3: {'pos': array([ 0.22691433, -0.1802301 ])},
 4: {'pos': array([0.22462413, 0.2452357 ])},
 5: {'pos': array([ 0.65037774, -0.18057473])},
 6: {'pos': array([-0.14587125, -0.13225175])},
 7: {'pos': array([0.05279257, 0.10579408])},
 8: {'pos': array([ 0.42384353, -0.46262269])},
 9: {'pos': array([-0.56650162,  0.13495046])},
 2: {'pos': [0.3, 0.5]}}
```

Hence the node is appended as a new dictionary `key/value` pair,

```
G.add_node(2, pos=pos[2])
G.add_edge(2, 8)

G.nodes()
# NodeView((0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2))
```

There is `Graph.add_nodes_from`, but it only updates the attributes if the node exists (does not remove and add the node anew), which makes sense:

```
G.add_nodes_from(sorted(G.nodes(data=True)))
G.nodes()
NodeView((0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 2))
```

So the way to go, is creating a graph anew, and assigning the sorted nodes, as in warped's answer:

```
H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from(sorted(G.nodes(data=True)))
H.add_edges_from(G.edges(data=True))

H.nodes()
# NodeView((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

Comment: What if the G.nodes returns string node values instead of an integer?

Answer (score 4):

A simple workaround would be to copy the nodes into a new graph:

```
H = nx.Graph()
H.add_nodes_from(sorted(G.nodes(data=True)))
H.add_edges_from(G.edges(data=True))
```

Comment: Can't we just use `sorted(G.nodes)` without copying nodes into a new graph?